# Partition one big list into two arrays in each step of the loop

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have one big list of single digit numbers in a single dimensional array like this:

```
list=[0,0,0,3,1,1,0,0,0,1,2,,........]
```

I want to split the list into two arrays (A & B) that shall take small streams,
such that starting at the beginning all 0s and the first non-zero number goes to the array 'A'[0] and the no of the selected numbers is noted in any variable say. 'maxa'
which shall make thing look like following,

```
A[0]=[0,0,0,3]

maxa = 4
```

and the numbers coming next (maxa-1)places goes to the array B[0]
so b shall look like this..

```
B[0]=[1,1,0]
```

Now this shall continue till all the nos in my *list* array run out.

I am using the below logic, but have hit a dead end. Could someone please help me out.

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < file.Count; ii++)
        {
            if (file.ElementAt(ii) == 0)
            {
                A[ii] = file.ElementAt(ii);
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                A[ii] = file.ElementAt(ii);
                count++;
            }
      }
```

Comment: your code doesn't have assigment to `B`. Also, could you please give the complete expected results for `A` and `B` on the defined list`

Comment: the two array A and B take different stream each time,always A start with zero and one sample not zero and B all the element after A stream less than one

Comment: such that:list=[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,2,2,1,0] so A  in the first step take A=[0,0,1] and B=[1,1] in second step A take A=[0,0,0,2] and B=[2,1,0]

Comment: `and B all the element after A stream less than one` - why then do you have `2,1,0` for `B`, if it takes elements less than one? Probably I'm too stupid in my morning...

Comment: because A in the second step take 4 element

Comment: list=[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,1,0] split this list by your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `file` has the `Count` property, I assume it might be a `List<int>`. If that's the case, you should use `file[ii]` rather than `file.ElementAt(ii)` to access its elements.

On the other hand, you should not be using indexers to assign to `A` and `B` (unless they're preallocated arrays). Rather, make them `List<int>` instances to which you can append integers dynamically using `Add`.

```
List<int> a = new List<int>();
List<int> b = new List<int>();

// The index along "file" we are currently reading.
int i = 0;

// Loop until the end of "file".
while (i < file.Count)
{
    // The index corresponding to the beginning of the current run of "A".
    int aStart = i;

    // Add first element to "A".
    a.Add(file[i++]);

    // Keep adding elements to "A" as long as predecessor was 0.
    while (file[i - 1] == 0 && i < file.Count)
        a.Add(file[i++]);

    // Calculate how many elements need to be added to "B"
    // (i.e. one less than how many were added to "A").
    int bTarget = i - aStart - 1;

    // Add that many elements to "B".
    while (bTarget-- > 0 && i < file.Count)
        b.Add(file[i++]);
}
```

Comment: Explain result on this `var file= new List<int> {0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,1,0};`, please.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: 
First run:
`A: 0, 0, 1` (read until first non-zero; total: *three*);
`B: 1, 1` (read *three* minus one elements).

Second run:
`A: 1` (read until first non-zero; total: *one*);
`B:` (read *one* minus one elements).

Third run:
`A: 0, 0, 2` (read until first non-zero; total: *three*);
`B: 2, 1` (read *three* minus one elements).

Fourth run:
`A: 0` (read until first non-zero; but we reach end-of-file).

Comment: `always A start with zero` from the comment of OP.

Comment: thank you Douglas you understand me and i try your code and it's working ,thanks for everybody

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Actually, `always A start with zero and one sample not zero`. You need to infer what the OP is trying to say. Using regex-like notation (assuming single-digit numbers), it would be `0*[1-9]`.

Comment: @Douglas:who can i use A and B in each step ,an example if i need to summation all the element of a & b each time, when i but this step,